# O que tem de errado no CSS que faz esse comportamento estranho entre os dois SOs?

Tags: css, windows, navegador-de-internet, osx

Estou tentando resolver um problema de desalinhamento no layout, que no Windows 10, com o Chrome mais recente ele muda o padding da altura de um botão. Este botão fica certinho no Mac OS Mojave, utilizando a mesma versão do Chrome, observe entre as imagens, a diferença:

**Mac:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Windows:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.item-descritores {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto -6% auto -6%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}
.selo-descritores {
    padding: 7px 10px 3px;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 4px;
    color: #777;
    border: none;
}

button {
   -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
   text-rendering: auto;
   color: buttontext;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   word-spacing: normal;
   text-transform: none;
   text-indent: 0px;
   text-shadow: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   align-items: flex-start;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-descritores"  style="">
   <button data-toggle="tooltip"  title="" class="selo-descritores" style="">EF15LP03</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Acredito que seja a renderização da fonte.

Comment: Vou colocar a fonte no CSS e ver se melhora.

Comment: Isso ocorre em outros navegadores? ou é sô nos SOs?

Comment: O que seria SOs?

Comment: Aqui tenho Win 10 e estou no Chrome e ficou assim http://prntscr.com/pza4y4 normal, não apresentou o mesmo problema que vc não. Outra coisa, o Chrome do Mac não usa Chromium, ele é Webkit igual o Safari até onde eu sei,

Comment: SOs - Sistema(s) Operacionai(s), seria isso.

Comment: Acredito que seja algum problema com alguns modelos de PCs... isso não acontece em todos os PCs da empresa aqui, só está aparecendo em dois modelos até agora... eu achei que poderia ser alguma extensão e carreguei a janela no modo anônimo, porém o problema persiste, achei que poderia realmente ser a fonte que pode estar salva na máquina que está diferente, eu ainda estou com dúvidas. [+]

Comment: [+] O problema não está só nesta tela, tem vários lugares do site, que desalinhou nestas telas... Ou seja, não creio que seja um problema de CSS, mas de adaptação para PCs com esta configuração.

Comment: Então @Renan, não testei em outros navegadores, mas no safari e no chrome no mac estão iguais. O Windows que tenho aqui é do pessoal de comunicação, então eu não posso instalar o safari para testar...

Comment: Provavelmente a font-family usada, ou a fonte é "nativa" do OS. Pessoalmente acho um baita exagero o uso de flex e grid para coisas simples, quando algo simples e mais "controlado" funcionaria muito bem, mas virou moda usar flex e grid, então a moda prevalece sobre o funcionar bem e "ensinam" que esse agora é o jeito certo... Se flex fosse melhor que fazer o simples para atingir o mesmo efeito, float teria sido "removido". Seu problema ser o flex ou a fonte, mas geralmente flex se não souber usar bem e na hora certa vai causar efeitos inesperados por falta de entendimento (da maioria).

Comment: Provavelmente se explicitar um line-height, fica mais constante a saída. De qualquer forma, precisaria [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema, pois o código tem muita informação que atrapalha na análise.